# Identify this insect, found in Central Vietnam, with long antennae, black wings, and red body

Tags: species-identification, entomology, species

Last year this insect landed on my hand when visiting the My Son city ruins in Central Vietnam.
I've been trying to identify the insect, but until now without result.

Can you help me? Or do you know who could?
[image]
[image]

Comment: That is a pretty cool bug.

Comment: Upvoted for the nice photo!

Answer (score 23):

This is a male [scale insect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect), which are Hemipterans from the superfamily Coccoidea.

The one in your photo is probably from the Genus *Drosicha*. Here is the Wikipedia page for [*Drosicha corpulenta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drosicha_corpulenta).

Here is an image, for comparison:

[image]

Here is another one, with black antennae, like yours:

[image]

There is no doubt that your specimen is a male because sexual dimorphism in Coccoidea is **huge**. Have a look at the females of *Drosicha*:

[image]

In conclusion, determining the exact species here is very difficult. However, we can be sure that the Genus of your insect is *Drosicha*.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before. It's [Identify this insect, found in Central Vietnam, with long antennae, black wings, and red body](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65921/identify-this-insect-found-in-central-vietnam-with-long-antennae-black-wings)

And it *is* Drosicha corpulenta. I'm having trouble finding a credible source.
Try these: google[http://nc.biodiv.tw/bbs/showpost.php?p=19392&postcount=1]

google[https://isabellevea.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/the-giant-scale-drosicha-corpulenta-on-uncovering-its-biology-part-1/]